# Soundcloud API is system glitch?

Tags: php, api, curl, soundcloud

Soundcloud API is system glitch?

I was able to access the Soundcloud with the `$url` below until last month.

However, there can not access now.

Executing either `$url` will return an empty array.

example1: Get track's info

```
$client_id = 'xxx'; 
$target = "https://soundcloud.com/account_name/track_name";
$url = "https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=$target&client_id=$client_id";  

// this will return "{}"
```

example2: Get search results

```
$client_id = 'xxx'; 
$search_words = "apple";
$url = 'https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=' . $client_id . '&q=' . $search_words;

// this will return also "{}"
```

I can't even get a clue how we could solve the issue.
Do you have any solutions?

Comment: what does the error say?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757071/php-debugging-curl

Comment: no error.this code return → "object(stdClass)#5396 (0) {}"

Comment: Since it was a URL issue, not an curl issue, I removed the curl part and fixed it to a concise question.